# MySQL two columns query to check records

Tags: mysql

I have a table say, events and fields are

id, event_id, dest_event_id

I would like to check my passed Ids of array into both the columns

so, I have done it via two separate queries.

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_id IN ('123' , '345');
```

if not,

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE dest_event_id IN ('123' , '345');
```

How can I do it using single query? can I use find_in_set?

**NOTE**:  want to check in dest_event_id when record does not exists in event_id

Thanks for your help

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_id IN ('123' , '345') or dest_event_id IN ('123' , '345')` work for you?

Comment: Why would you need to use `FIND_IN_SET()`? That's only needed if the list is in a comma-delimited string.

Comment: @Barmar I want to check in dest_event_id only if records not exists in event_id

Comment: Does `event_id` or `dest_event_id` contain a comma-delimited list?

Comment: If those individual queries work, then you don't need `FIND_IN_SET()` when you combine them.

Comment: Add that clarification to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to put both conditions together:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_id IN ('123' , '345') or dest_event_id IN ('123' , '345')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following Query

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE 123 IN (event_id, dest_event_id) OR
                     345 IN (event_id, dest_event_id);
```